# Rails/AJAX partial rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I made an application that has a `project` model. The model has some information stored in it, and a user can add comments to the `project` (using the `comment` model). In the show view of a project I want the user to be able to switch between an "info" partial (containing the project information, and a "comment" partial (containing the comments wrote on the project). I want to do this using AJAX. So I will have two buttons: Information & Comments.

Now I know how to render a partial based on a "remote link", but I'll also have to find out which link was clicked. So far I can render one partial when one link is clicked like so:

```
// In show.html.haml

= link_to("Information", :project, :id => "link_one", :remote => true)
= link_to("Comments", :project, :id => "link_two", :remote => true)

#partial_window


// In show.js.haml
$("#partial_window").html("#{j(render("comments"))}")
```

Now this renders the `_comment.html.haml` partial when I click on one of the links. What I need to know is how to check *which* link was clicked, and then render the appropriate partial: `_info.html.haml` or `_comments.html.haml`.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why do you need to know which link was clicked? Wouldn't each link correspond to a different controller/action and therefore execute its own javascript?

Comment: Well I don't have any additional controller action set up, this is all happening in the `show` action... The code you see in the question is everything I have so far :( I'm fairly new to javascript!

Comment: The way I visualize this working is when you click on, say "Information", an action is fired on the `ProjectController` that clears the `div` on the page and fills it with the information.  Now, when you click "Comments", an action is fired on the `CommentsController` that clears the `div` and refills it with comments.  Does that make sense? I can try pseudo coding if you think that would help

Comment: Well it makes sense, but I wouldn't know how to get it to work ;) Because I need the project to be passed on the comments, So only the comments on that particular project are loaded. Can you explain how to set up your example? Also, I don't know what you mean by pseudo coding... Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: pseudo coding means outlining the genreal form of code (fake code) but not actually writing it in a specific language.  It is used to just share ideas and concepts before actually implementing the logic.  I'll write up an answer for you

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Something like this *should* work.  We are going to use nested routes.  Check out [ryan's screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources) (a little old, but it gets the point across) or this more [updated version about nested forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) (uses the same principles).  You'll have to pay for the updated version, but I find my RailsCast subscription to be more than worth the $9/month. Also, here are the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) for examples.

`config/routes.rb`

```
resources :projects do
  resources :comments
end
```

`comments_controller.rb`

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    project = Project.find params[:project_id]
    @comments = project.comments
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html #responds with default html file
     format.js #this will be the javascript file we respond with
    end
  end
end
```

`views/comments/index.js.erb`

```
$('#holderDiv').empty().append('<ul> <%= j render @comments %> </li>')
```

This uses a nifty thing of rails that looks for a `comment` partial and renders it for each comment in `@comments`. The j helper escapes javascript and pretty much inserts the rendered partial into the `append` function.

`views/comments/_comment.html.erb`

```
 <li> <%= @comment.description %> </li>
```

So we've now cleared the `#holdingDiv` and inserted our comments.  For `information`, maybe something like this:

`projects_controller.rb`

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @project = Project.find params[:id]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

`views/project/index.js.erb`

```
 $('#holderDiv').empty().append('<%= j render 'information', information: @project.information %>')
```

`views/project/_information.html.erb`

```
<h2>
  <%= information.title %>
</h2>
<p>
  <%= infomration.details %>
</p>
```

Then, your remote links would be something like:

```
= link_to("Information", @project, :remote => true)
= link_to("Comments", project_comments_url(@project), :remote => true)
```

I had to make some assumptions about what your data structures were. Let me know where I've confused you.

Also, I am sure I have some typos, sorry for that. I did not test this, just went off the top of my head.

Comment: I think JS filenames in views should end with `js.erb` instead of `.js` cause you are using `<%= %>` inside