# Rails 4 ajax load content in bootstrap tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the same problem as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532483/how-do-i-fetch-the-content-for-each-tab-using-ajax-rails4-bootstrap3).

However, I still find it hard to comprehend the solution.

The view:

```
/ Nav tabs
%ul.nav.nav-tabs
  %li.active
    =link_to "Tab1", "#tab1", html_options = { "data-toggle" => "tab" }
  %li
    =link_to "Tab2", "#tab2", html_options = { "data-toggle" => "tab" }
  %li
    =link_to "Tab3", "#tab3", html_options = { "data-toggle" => "tab" }

/ Tab panes
.tab-content
  .tab-pane.active#tab1
    %p Fetch content
  .tab-pane.active#tab2
    %ul.nav.nav-pills
      %li.active= link_to 'Overview', "#overview", html_options = { "data-toggle" => "tab"}
      %li= link_to 'Details', "#details", html_options = { "data-toggle" => "tab"}
      .tab-content
        .tab-pane.active#overview
          %p Fetch overview
        .tab-pane.active#details
          %p Fetch details
  .tab-pane.active#tab3
    %p Fetch content
```

The controller:

```
def show
  @data_tab1 = User.admin
  @data_tab2 = User.member
  @data_tab3 = User.moderator
end
```

I don't want those three sets of data loaded in each request. Such that when clicking the second tab and @data_tab2 loads.

I found this code that might be useful:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab
  if ($(target).is(':empty')) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "**WHAT SHOULD I PUT IN HERE**",
      error: function(data){
        alert("There was a problem");
      },
      success: function(data){
        $(target).html(data);
      }
  })
 }
})
```

SO, I want to know:

**1. how to change the active state of each clicked tab**

**2. how to ajax load tab data**

Ajax call with error.

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'e.target.data("target")')
    (anonymous function) (1, line 3)
    dispatch (jquery.js, line 4642)
    handle (jquery.js, line 4310)
    trigger (jquery.js, line 4551)
    (anonymous function) (jquery.js, line 5261)
    each (jquery.js, line 384)
    each (jquery.js, line 137)
    trigger (jquery.js, line 5260)
    (anonymous function) (bootstrap.js, line 1048)
    next (bootstrap.js, line 1091)
    activate (bootstrap.js, line 1098)
    show (bootstrap.js, line 1043)
    (anonymous function) (bootstrap.js, line 1113)
    each (jquery.js, line 384)
    each (jquery.js, line 137)
    Plugin (bootstrap.js, line 1108)
    clickHandler (bootstrap.js, line 1137)
    dispatch (jquery.js, line 4642)
    handle (jquery.js, line 4310)
```

And I would like to give each tab-pane a partial, how do I dynamically change the partial name in the controller? E.g.

```
/ Tab panes
.tab-content
  .tab-pane.active#tab1
    = render "tab1"
  .tab-pane.active#tab2
    = render "tab2"
  .tab-pane.active#tab3
    = render "tab3"
```

Should I use different instance variable?

```
def show
  @data_tab = User.admin
  @data_tab = User.member if params[:tab] == "member"
  @data_tab = User.moderator if params[:tab] == "moderator"
end
```

OR

```
def show
  @data_tab1 = User.admin
  @data_tab2 = User.member if params[:tab] == "member"
  @data_tab3 = User.moderator if params[:tab] == "moderator"
end
```

**Update:**

It keeps rendering the same set of data as shown in the vid clip.

http://tinypic.com/r/28k5302/8

Please advise.

Comment: The questioner, do you have the final code somewhere uploaded? It's a bit hard to navigate thru via the comments. Thx!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1. how to change the active state of each clicked tab

If you look at [`bootstrap tabs markup`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), it says:

> You can activate a tab or pill navigation without writing any JavaScript by simply specifying data-toggle="tab" or data-toggle="pill" on an element

So your markup needs to be like this:

```
/ Nav tabs
%ul.nav.nav-tabs
  %li.active
    =link_to "Tab1", "#tab1", html_options = { "data-toggle" => "tab" }
  %li
    =link_to "Tab2", "#tab2", html_options = { "data-toggle" => "tab" }
  %li
    =link_to "Tab3", "#tab3", html_options = { "data-toggle" => "tab" }

/ Tab panes
.tab-content
  .tab-pane.active#tab1
    %p Fetch content
  .tab-pane#tab2
    %ul.nav.nav-pills
      %li.active
        = link_to 'Overview', "#overview", html_options = { "data-toggle" => "tab"}
      %li
        = link_to 'Details', "#details", html_options = { "data-toggle" => "tab"}
      .tab-content
        .tab-pane.active#overview
          %p Fetch overview
        .tab-pane#details
          %p Fetch details
  .tab-pane#tab3
    %p Fetch content
```

Note: **You need to apply active class only on the tab you want to show.**

> 2. how to ajax load tab data

a. **Create a custom route to which you want your ajax request to go to or you can just use the show action for it.**

b. **We need to add some data attribute so that we know which tab is being clicked. We can then target it in backend.**

```
/ Nav tabs
%ul.nav.nav-tabs
  %li.active
    =link_to "Tab1", "#tab1", data: {toggle: "tab", target: "admin", href: "#{your_show_action_path}
  %li
    =link_to "Tab2", "#tab2", data: {toggle: "tab", target: "member", href: "#{your_show_action_path}
  %li
    =link_to "Tab3", "#tab3", data: {toggle: "tab", target: "moderator", href: "#{your_show_action_path}
/ Tab panes
.tab-content
  .tab-pane.active#tab1
    %p // this will be activated by default so you can load default content here
  .tab-pane#tab2
    %ul.nav.nav-pills
      %li.active
        = link_to 'Overview', "#overview", html_options = { "data-toggle" => "tab"}
      %li
        = link_to 'Details', "#details", html_options = { "data-toggle" => "tab"}
      .tab-content
        .tab-pane.active#overview
          %p Fetch overview
        .tab-pane#details
          %p Fetch details
  .tab-pane#tab3
    %p Fetch content
```

c. Use JS to fire your ajax request

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var target = $(this).data("target");
  var href = $(this).data("href");
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: href,
    data: {tab: target},
    dataType: "script"
  });
})
```

d. Now you can load tabs content depending on the tab variable send by ajax request.

```
def show
  @data_tab = User.admin
  @data_tab = User.member if params[:tab] == "member"
  @data_tab = User.moderator if params[:tab] == "moderator"
end

#show.js.erb
$(".tab-pane.active").html("your content here");
```

> And I would like to give each tab-pane a partial, how do I dynamically change the partial name in the controller? Should I use different instance variable?

*If content is same then you can use the same partial and same instance variable but if it's different then you can check params for the value of target variable and then accordingly render your partial in js.erb*

**Update:**

> 1: How to dynamically change .tab-pane.active, as I would set member and moderator empty partials such that when I click "member" tab, the partial will be filled with ajax data and add an "active" class to that pane?

You don't need to add active class here because if you have bootstrap js in your app then it'll automatically set active class on the tab you'll click, checkout [`bootstrap docs`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

> 2:How can js.erb respond to different instance variables and render different partials?

When you click on a tab we get the data-target attribute and send it as params in the ajax request and then in js.erb file we are checking for these param values to render partials.

> 3.How to prevent previously clicked tab to send an ajax request?

Not sure what you mean here but previously clicked tab won't and shouldn't send ajax request. If you are clicking on 2 tabs quickly then that's normal to send 2 ajax requests as in the end it'll always show up the active tab.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I cannot get the ajax request working. Do I need a respond_to rendering?

Comment: @Thequestioner ahh sorry my bad. It wasn't working because of the js error. I have edited my answer and it should be fix now :)

Comment: `<% if @admin %>
$(".tab-pane.active").html("#{render @admin}");
<% elsif @moderator %>
$(".tab-pane.active").html("#{render @moderator}");
<% end %>` I tried this code to render different partials but no success, please advise. I know that rails would infer @moderator to a partial _moderator.html.erb.

Comment: The js is working, but the controller keeps returning the value of `User.admin` and the html does not change according to the value.

Comment: Thequestioner can you post logs when you change tabs? Also since it's  a js.erb file so you need to render partials like this: $(".tab-pane.active").html("<%=j render @admin %>");

Comment: I have few Qs. 1: How to dynamically change `.tab-pane.active`, as I would set member and moderator empty partials such that when I click "member" tab, the partial will be filled with ajax data and add an "active" class to that pane? 2:How can js.erb respond to different instance variables and render different partials? 3.How to prevent previously clicked tab to send an ajax request?Sorry for chunks of Qs, I am new to ajax, I just want a tab behaviour just like  [railscasts](http://railsexperience.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/jquery-rendering-tabs/) in bootstrap way.

Comment: @Thequestioner no issues. I have updated my answer. Let me know if that makes sense to you :)

Comment: Mandeep, is it possible to do somehow infinite scrolling as well? I mean there is already  show.js.erb response for changing tab, but I would like to add infinite scrolling to each tab which also needs js.erb response. Should I create a new js.erb file or I could do it in the same show.js.erb file? How can I separate the different triggers (clicking on tab/ scrolling)?

Comment: @SzilardMagyar they are different actions so just make a different method and call it when you reach at the bottom of page. You can also use [infinite-scroll](https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll)

Comment: Mandeep, could you elaborate it a bit? How would you do this in this code above if you had to do the infinite scrolling for all the 3 tabs. (I know it's show action, but let's just say we have here index action and list of user admins, moderators and members.) I don't need the js code or infinite scroll code, I just would like to understand the structure: routes/ controller_name#actions/ js.erb file names.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar it's hard to understand your problem so you should ask a separate question with all the details so that someone could help you

Comment: @Mandeep, you are right, I just created a question for better understanding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817690/rails-ajax-js-erb-same-route-more-actions . Could you pls take a look at it? I guess you can solve this problem in no time.

Comment: @Mandeep, I can't figure this one out :(. Could you pls help me out then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817690/rails-ajax-js-erb-same-route-more-actions

Answer (score 0):

1. To change active state of tab you need add `active` class to it (and remove it from previous tab)
2. To load data you need put to `url` of your ajax request your path to show action (with param datects what tab need to load). Or you can do it with remote links - good sample is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13958574/2174582)