# Rails 4: Dynamically rendering a form on the same page with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I seem to be having some trouble finding some good information on how to go about dynamically presenting forms on the same view. What I mean is, for example, A user clicks an "Add Sub-element" link on the show view for an "Element", and then is presented with a small form for adding a Sub-Element, and of course the same type of thing for editing existing Sub-Elements, on the same Show View using AJAX/JS/jQuery or something.

I was trying REST-in-place, but to no avail, as I have several nested objects (some within other nested objects), and that doesn't seem to work well with in-line-editing.

I believe my lack of information is coming from using incorrect search terminology, so any help would be appreciated to point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to do it, one is using remote forms, like this [railscasts example](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised?view=asciicast) or the detailed [answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941215/rails-ajax-partial-rendering/13958574#13958574). Another would be to call a controller from jQuery and render (similar to my code here):

in javascript:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#user-list-body', function (e) {
    var url = '/get_user_list/
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        datatype: 'html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            $('#user_table tbody').append(data);
        }
     });
});
```

in controller (**note:** drastically simplified version):

```
  def get_user_list
     @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => false, :partial => 'users/users_list'}
    end
  end
```